# Excel Formula To LookUp

Tags: excel-formula

I have two sheets. **Sheet1** has BrandName and the Price.
**Sheet2** sheet has same info, BrandName and Price.  But this sheet has multiple Prices for same Brand.
I want a formula to lookup the closest price for a brand from **Sheet2** to **Sheet1**.
Very Much similar to This

**Sheet1**
Brand-------Price------Closest Price
A--------------100  --------?
B--------------200---------?

**Sheet2**
Brand-------Price
A--------------100
A--------------105
B--------------201
B--------------210
B--------------205

Answer (score 1):

The formula in your Sheet1!C2 could be

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MIN(IF(IF(Sheet2!A:A=A2,ABS(Sheet2!B:B-B2))=MIN(IF(Sheet2!A:A=A2,ABS(Sheet2!B:B-B2))),ROW(Sheet2!A:A))))}
```

This is an array formula. Input the formula into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to finish.

Array formulas are poor in performance. So if it is slow in calculation, shrink the ranges related to Sheet2. Try `Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000` and `Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10000` for example.